# FXML and lambda expressions in Java not working?

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, java-8

I'm working on rewriting  my simple Contacts app from normal JAVA FX to FXML.THe problem is in Lambda expressions. I have interface like:

```
interface ObjectCreator {
void create(String[] array);
}
```

And the problem is when i use this CSVFileReader:

```
public static class CSVFileReader {
    String fileName;

    CSVFileReader(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    void read(ObjectCreator creator) {
        try {
            BufferedReader csv = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String row = csv.readLine();
            while (row != null) {
                creator.create(row.split(","));
                row = csv.readLine();
            }
            csv.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

In this code i use lambda expression to read Contacts from file:

```
@FXML
public void openFile() {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File fileE = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(scene.getWindow());
    if (fileE != null) {

        CSVFileReader reader = new CSVFileReader(fileE.getName());
        data.clear();

        reader.read(v -> 
        data.add(new Contact(v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3])));


    }
    System.out.println("open list");
}
```

I use JDK 1.8.65 so preeety new one. Problem is that there is no error or exception just looks like code "v->data.add(new Contact(v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]))" would not be invoked.
Question is am I doing something wrong or it just wont be working??

Comment: You need to be more specific about problem you are facing (what makes you think that it is *not working*?). Do you get compilation error, or runtime exception, or maybe incorrect results?

Comment: Sorry you are right the problem is that no result is being read from file where are like 3 records. And there  is no error or exception just looks like the code "v ->  data.add(new Contact(v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]))" would not be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok no question, after futher studying my app i discovered i was taking

```
fileE.getName();
```

and i should take

```
fileE.getAbsolutePath();
```

So the app would look in proper location for a file.